# Integrate Visual studio code with selenium Web driver into Azure DevOps

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops

I learned testing scripts selenium web driver with java in Visual studio code
But now i want to connect or integrate Visual studio code into Azure DevOpS to perform Automation testing.

Can anyone please help me out

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)